# Edit Item Class based views - Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-templates

I need to edit an item, more specifically, to do a CRUD on an object I retrieve by using class based views on Django 1.5.7

The ListView code on views.py is as follows:

```
class UsarioList(ListView):
    model = UsuarioFidetel
    template_name = 'all_list.html'
```

Now I'm trying to add a button to my template, in order to edit each obj item from my db table.

This is my template code:

```
{% if object_list %}
{% for obj in object_list %}
   <ul style="list-style:none; margin-left:30px; padding:0px"><tr>
   <li><label>Tipo de Cedula: </label><td>{{ obj.tipo_cedula }}</td></li><td><a href='/usario/{{ obj.tipo_cedula }}'>Editar</a></td>
   <li><label>Cedula: </label><td>{{ obj.cedula }}</td></li>
   <li><label>Nombre: </label><td>{{ obj.nombre }}</td></li>
   <li><label>Apellido: </label><td>{{ obj.apellido }}</td></li>
   <li><label>Fecha de nacimiento: </label><td>{{ obj.fecha_nacimiento }}</td></li>
   <li><label>Estado Civil: </label><td>{{ obj.estado_civil }}</td></li>
   <li><label>Sexo: </label><td>{{ obj.sexo }}</td></li>
   <li><label>Correo electronico: </label><td>{{ obj.correo }}</td></li>
   <li><label>ID de Usuario: </label><td>{{ obj.usuario }}</td></li>
   </tr></ul>
{% endfor %}
{% if is_paginated %}
    <div class="pagination">
        <span class="page-links">
            {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                <a href="/fidetel/usario?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">&lt;</a>
            {% endif %}
            <span class="page-current">
                Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
            </span>
            {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                <a href="/fidetel/usario?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">&gt;</a>
            {% endif %}
        </span>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

{% else %}

No existen Usuarios

{% endif %}

If you look on `obj.tipo_cedula` line, I've added a table with this code:

```
<td><a href='/usario/{{ obj.tipo_cedula }}'>Editar</a></td>
```

Apparently it works, but when I click on it, it throws this error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:9001/usario/V
```

It is actually working somehow, BUT I need this edition to happen on the very same page, where I'm seeing the data.

I mean, the button should "open" the field so I can edit and Update data.

Btw, my template is for listview, it's called `usuariofidetel_list.html` should I use a form for it?

How can I achieve this?

I hope I've explained myself, thanks in advance!

Comment: The reason its not working is because your edit link is pointing to the same page as your list view, you should point it to your edit view.

Comment: So I should create a 'class UsarioEdit(UpdateView):'?

Comment: Yes, something like that.

Comment: Well, I don't think it's just that, there must be something else I'm doing wrong. We'll see. Thanks.